# How do you use MSAL to connect to Azure DevOps from vanilla JS in browser, with no-backend or AD tenant

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

If I use a Personal Access Token, I can access all Azure DevOps REST APIS by including the PAT in the header.  This works great from NodeJS, PowerShell and curl, but I want to do the same thing from JS running in a web-browser, without any server-side code.  Just purely from the JS in the browser.

Now, I *could* prompt the user to enter their PAT and store it in local storage, but I'd rather not do that.  Instead, I'd like to prompt the user to log in and get a token that way.  Microsoft has the MSAL library to do that, and they have sample code on how to do this from JavaScript in the browser.  Unfortunately, for some reason, they require that you also create an Azure AD Tenant along with a client ID.  I don't want to use Azure cloud for anything.  I just want my users to access an existing company Azure DevOps server.  As I said I can already access these resources using a PAT that the user has to create from the portal themselves.  I want to avoid that step and have them log in to get a token.  Seems simple enough.   Am I missing something?

Why is a tenant even needed for this?

Comment: From the MSAL doc for Java: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java. It supports many Microsoft identities such AAD identities and Microsoft accounts. Not sure about how users are required to create an AAD with a client ID?What happens if they don't provide the client ID?

Comment: @KimXu-MSFT I have a feeling this is required because oauth 2 server has to contact the app's public server -- That's how it works.   So someone has to be the delegate for Oauth2.   In the case of "Azure DevOps" connection, Microsoft is the delegate but it also needs to know who you are, thus the client ID.  Otherwise, any random web-page  could do authorization and I don't believe OAuth2 allows that.   Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: Yes, your understanding about OAuth2 is correct for me. Also, check this link: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki. The Overview 2 point says: Pre-requisite: Before using MSAL4J you will have to register your applications with Azure AD.

Comment: @KimXu-MSFT if you want to put that down as the answer, I'll go ahead and accept it as the answer to this question.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, @Art Ghangsta , appreciated to do so!

Comment: Hi @Art Ghangsta , have you got a chance to check my post? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki

> Before using MSAL4J you will have to register your applications with
> Azure AD.

[image]

In conclusion, to use MSAL to connect to Azure DevOps from vanilla JS in browser, you need to register your App with Azure AD first to acquire the client ID for authorization.